# regarding cuda performance optimization

Tags: performance, cuda

For those cuda functions which are only going to be called from device, does it matter in terms of performance if we declare them  __ global __ or __ device __ ?

Comment: Your question makes no sense - you can't call `__global__`functions from device code in CUDA. Kernels cannot launch other kernels.

Answer (score 1):

As of CUDA 4.1, `__global__` functions cannot be called from `__device__` functions.

Comment: As of CUDA 5.0, device code can launch `__global__` kernel functions on devices that support it (CC 3.5 and later). :)